# Unable to render a component based off function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render several different components and passing it's props via a mapping. `componentInfo` contains an array of the information that's being passed.

```
displayComponent() {
 this.state.componentInfo.map(info => {
  return (
    <SomeComponent info={info}/>
   )
 })
}
```

In my React component, I want these components generated based off a button click with fires the `displayComponent` function.

```
render() {
 return (
  <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
   <RaisedButton label="DISPLAY" onClick={this.displayComponent} />
  </div>
}
```

However, I'm unable to display the components. Why is this?

Comment: You are not rendering `displayComponent` anywhere just calling it on click

Comment: @Sagivb.g Should I render it within my function then?

Comment: In the current setup you can't render it anywhere. you should have one function that updates the state with an array of components, and another function that renders them so you can call it inside the render

Comment: Is there any possible way I can see an example?

Comment: Yeah i posted an example

Answer (score 1):

You are not rendering `displayComponent`, just invoking it on a click event.
In the current setup of your code i find it hard to achieve what you are after, I would separate the objects inside the state:

```
  state = {
    showComponents: false,
    componentInfo: ['info 1', 'info 2', 'info 3'],
    components: []
  }
```

Then you can populate the components array and render it conditionally.

Running example:

```js
const SomeComponent = ({ info }) => <div>{info}</div>;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showComponents: false,
    componentInfo: ['info 1', 'info 2', 'info 3'],
    components: []
  }

  setComponents = () => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const { componentInfo } = state;
      const nextComponents = componentInfo.map(info => <SomeComponent info={info} />);
      return {
        components: nextComponents,
        showComponents: true
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { showComponents, components } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.setComponents}>Set Components</button>
        <hr/>
        {showComponents && components}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```